# How to Shuffle List in Python One Time

Tags: python-3.x

How can I shuffle a list of elements in Python so that it is shuffled only once, and every time I run the code, it gives me the same shuffled list as the first time?

Try using the shuffle function, but repeat the process every time I run the code.

Comment: Save the list to a text file?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Comment: You can use `random.seed()` to make all random calculations the same, including the shuffle function from the random library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee the same order for each occurrence, since `shuffle` uses a random number to change the order. It would be much simpler to create the `list` in the required order once, and paste that into the program.

Comment: This isn't entirely true, it's a pseudo random number generator, basically a sequence that appears random but setting the seed will cause the same sequence to be generated every time.

Comment: You are correct but for all intents and purposes it is random. and it is not a good idea to rely on such a feature to ensure consistent results, as there are too many opportunities to make simple errors.

Comment: Using the seed is totally reliable, I've used it as a method to ensure reproducibility for decades for engineering simulations, financial models and more recently machine learning. It's a standard scientific method.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth Sure, but I am guessing that you know exactly what you are doing.